# convert int to string in android?

Tags: java

I want to store 1 to 110  in string array variable, when i tried am getting null pointer exception.

```
String age[];
for(int i=0;i<=101;i++){
  age[i]=Integer.toString(i);
}
```

Comment: Your verbiage doesn't match your code (0 vs 1, 101 vs 110).  Which do you want?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to initialize the String-array first:

```
String[] age = new String[110];
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
String[] age = new String[102];
String.valueOf(int value);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String abc = String.valueOf(int);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the String array first:

```
String[] age = new String[111];
```

Answer (score 1):

You got error because you haven't initialized it :

```
String[] age = new String[111];
```